# Is this ram compatible with my desktop?

Tags: memory

I want to buy this: [http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820148540&cm_re=ram-*-20-148-540-*-Product](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820148540&cm_re=ram-_-20-148-540-_-Product)
But I don't know if it's compatible with my Dell XPS 8500 which is a desktop.

And if anyone happens to know- how many slots of ram my computer can hold, please tell me.

Comment: This user is seeking (or seems to be) seeking the process to determine RAM compatibility.  That being said, the OP IMHO could have done more research before posing the question, because this is well trodden question.  Despite the wording of the question, it is specific and actionable.   The OP has not asked for a hardware shopping recommendation and is asking a compatibility / capacity question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the Crucial Ballistix Sport 8GB 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM DDR3 1600 (PC3 12800) is compatible with your Dell XPS 8500 computer:

[image]

Comment: What is CAS Latency and how does it affect it, and how does having a higher or lower voltage affect it? (it - being the computer)

Comment: @Bryton Please do not ask further questions as comments. That comment sounds like the beginnings of a pretty good question to me, assuming it hasn't been asked already (search first, and if you don't find anything that looks similar, post it as a question).

Comment: @Bryton Your CAS latency question should be posed in a new thread.  It would be quicker for you to Google and research the answer than to pose the question and wait for answers.

Answer (score 1):

here is a list of compatible RAM chips for your device. http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-memory-for/Dell/xps-8500

You can also look inside the machine or go to dells website to look up specs. It looks like it will run up to 32GB and has 4 RAM slots.